# Redirecting messages from syslogd

Tags: linux, terminal, centos-6, syslogd

I'm currently using a CentOS 6 cluster which is having some issues on one node that is triggering a syslogd message:

```
Message from syslogd@node005 at Sep  7 14:23:04 ...
 kernel: Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 3d on CPU 0.

Message from syslogd@node005 at Sep  7 14:23:04 ...
 kernel: Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?

Message from syslogd@node005 at Sep  7 14:23:04 ...
 kernel: Dazed and confused, but trying to continue
```

This is being investigated by the system folks, but in the meantime I'd like to use the other nodes to do work. However the message hits every 15 seconds or so, no matter where I'm logged in and even while I'm in vim. Its making work impossible.

Is there any way to redirect *as a user* the output to /dev/null or a file or anywhere but my terminal?

Comment: I've seen something similar in my logs dealing with a networking hiccup in OVh's datacenters. I'll look around and see if I can find anything to do with this in CentOS, but I've never seen messages with personality appear in a syslog before, though I abandoned CentOS 6 for Debian a few years ago.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/575639/kernel-uhhuh-nmi-received-for-unknown-reason-31-on-cpu-3) can be of assistance. It appears to be bad or outdated hardware, such as a video card, though I assume your server wouldn't have that installed, it's still a possibility. I assume it's an add-on card somewhere.

Comment: Actually, we do indeed have Nvidia GPUs installed (its a physics computational cluster) and this is being looked at by the hardware vendor. But its still very distracting while trying to work.